# Why my app is as "hidden" on Google play?

Tags: android, search-engine, google-play

First sorry for my bad English : I'm French and I may make a few mistakes.

I created an app and I uploaded it last month on the Google Play store. You can find it here without problems : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.malerbati.fourInAMine.

The problem is : my app is almost impossible to find with the search engine ! When I search "4 in a mine", my app name, in Google Play, it only appears at the 20th result !

Besides, the app didn't appear at the "Top news" when I uploaded it.
I remember that the last app I created counted 200 downloads 1 day after its release, obviously thanks to the "Top news" thing... whereas this app has only 65 downloads, 1 month after ! And when I look at the statistics, I see that 100% of the downloaders are French (my country), which means that ALL the persons who got my app found it with word of mouth ! That's quite inefficient...

Therefore, here are my questions : why the hell can't we see my app easily, like the others ? Did anyone else encounter the same problem ? I have some suppositions about the origin of the problem :

- The last app I created was a big failure : 95% of the people uninstalled it, essentially because the game was too hard. Does Google Play search engine take this into account ?
- I created my last app last year. There must be much more apps now. Is my app simply hidden by the (too) big number of other apps ?
- My app is very smaller than the last one (only 300 ko, against 3 Mo). Is that taken in account too ?

Thank you in anticipation. I really want to know where the problem is.

Comment: [According to AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/number-of-android-apps), there are generally at least 500 apps uploaded to Google Play **each day**. It's unrealistic to assume that you're going to get featured in the market just for uploading something. You should consider yourself lucky that you got featured the first time. What you are experiencing is just a reality of Android development for those without a budget for advertising or some way to get yourself known.

Comment: @Tim, I don't think he's looking to be featured, exactly, just wants to show up in a simple list of "What's new".  But Google Play doesn't do that at the moment.  As you say, there's a deluge of new titles.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, when I said 'featured' I just meant 'being placed anywhere that would get seen by casual surfers outside of a search that hits your keywords'.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few resources to help:

[How Android Developers Can Thrive with Google Play](http://techcrunch.com/2012/05/20/how-android-developers-can-thrive-with-google-play/)

> - **Maximize search potential in your app title**: identify your most successful keywords and make sure to include them in your app title.  In fact, this is so critical to success (potentially 80 to 100 places in your search ranking), that you should seriously consider removing your app name from your title and focus your description on the best keywords. Include the app name in the body of the app description – users will still be able to find it by name. Unlike iOS, the body description is searched under Google Play.
> - **Use, but don’t overuse, keywords**: try to use the best keywords at five times the body of your app description. This can affect search ranking from 10 to 20 places.  Anything over five times has no additional benefit, so don’t overdo it.
> - **Test your search parameters**: the above recommendations are guidelines based on accumulated experience, but search results can vary based on many factors.
> - **Steady efforts work best**: Google Play’s ranking algorithm is tilted towards long term user acquisition – apps that acquire and retain satisfied users are rewarded with higher ranks.  Advertising campaigns should be run over a longer term and sustained over two to three months, as opposed to the short bursts of activity often seen in the iOS market.
> - **Use closed loop attribution and target long term users**:  since retained users have an important impact in ranking, use closed loop marketing to ensure you are identifying and utilizing ad sources that bring loyal users.
> - Don’t be afraid to experiment and test market your strategy with Android. You can apply these learnings to your iOS versions and reduce your costs and risks.

[Google Play Optimization Secrets - 5 Helpful Tips](http://www.silverbackstrategies.com/internet-marketing/google-play-optimization-secrets-5-helpful-tips)

The second link contains more information that leans more towards marketing and sales strategy than practical steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your application contains a number of very common words.  Some of the most common, smallest little auxiliary words are probably discarded because they return a hit on everything.

If you put quotes around it, then Google Play will search for the whole sequence.  When I search `4 in a mine` then I basically don't see your app.  When I search `"4 in a mine"`, then your app is the *only* result.

I understand that this information doesn't really help you because, while it answers your question, you cannot control users' behavior.  You would do better to make your title unique.  That of course also makes it less descriptive and harder for users to remember.  It's an unavoidable tradeoff.

**Responding to your other questions:**

I would be surprised if the success or failure of your other game had anything to do with the search relevance of this one.  I could believe the uninstall rate affects the search relevance of the uninstalled title.

The huge number of new apps being published does mean that you want to get onto the virtuous cycle of installs quickly.  So, the same day that you upload the app, get onto your social networks and tell all your friends and followers that you have a new game to try out.  Make sure it works on most of the devices they are using. :-)

A listing page that describes your app well helps you get some collateral benefit from the "Users also viewed" lists for searches that lead to similar games.  You gain a little more collateral benefit by publishing additional apps that appear under "More from developer".  It may not be a big boost, but it is a feedback path -- probably the only one that you directly control.

I would be surprised if app size made any difference at all.

**To sum up:**

I think your problem is your title is composed entirely of either tiny words that get discarded, or common words that match lots of other games.  You can easily locate your app by searching for the phrase all in one piece, but users won't do that.  So work on combining unique terms that only you use, with descriptive terms that help the search engine determine your relevance in searches.  And follow it up with some marketing.

Comment: *I would be surprised if the success or failure of your other game had anything to do with the search relevance of this one.* I thought I did remember reading somewhere that Google does use your developer history to rank future applications. Unfortunately was not able to find any official source on this, but it could be a potential factor.

Comment: You won't find official sources giving specifics about how application discovery is implemented.  Even 'rank' has to take context into account: different people may see different results for the same search.  'Relevance' would be a more accurate term.